# Export TypeScript Class with 'export' as part of the result?

Tags: typescript

I have written a TypeScript Class

```
export class myClass{
   //Code here...
}
```

I would like the following result af compile:

```
export function myClass() {

}
```

The compiled JS is for a Blazor WASM app.

How should I write my TypeScript?

With Blazor I have the opportunity to JSInvoke javascript code but from what I have learned it only invokes exported functions.

/* UPDATE */

With target set to ES5 I can get the TS code transpiled to:

```
function myClass() {
}
```

But I need the 'export' in front?

```
export function myClass() {

}
```

Comment: `class` syntax and `export` were added in the same version of JavaScript (ECMAScript 2015), but `class` was in real-world environments much earlier than `export`/`import` were. Why do you want to down-compile `class` but keep `export`? If your target supports `export`/`import`, it supports `class`.

Comment: Blazor has a JSInvoke method that takes an exported function:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: Yes, but again, if it supports `export`, it supports `class`, so it's not clear to me how that answers what I asked. Again, is there some reason you need `class` converted to `function`? The result of a `class` definition is a constructor function. But separately: Does JSInvoke know to use `new`? Because you don't want to call a constructor function (whether created via `class` or via `function`) without `new`.

Comment: I am not sure that I can answer your question. 
My ultimate goal is to use Webpack and Typescript and transpile TS code to something Blazor JSInvoke can consume. I am experimenting in the dark and need some advice.

Comment: The first thing you need to know is what JavaScript version the Blazor JSInvoke engine knows how to understand. If it understands `export`, then it's almost guaranteed it understands `class`, so you can set your TypeScript project with the [`target`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#target) option set to (say) `"ES2020"` and the [`module`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#module) option to `ES2020` (or `ES2015`). Then the output will use `export` and `class`. But if JSInvoke just *calls* the function you export, without using `new`, then exporting a constructor function...

Comment: ...won't work. You'll need to export a wrapper that calls the constructor function via `new` instead (or don't use a constructor function / `class` at all). I don't know the environment, so I can't help more than that.